# Synapse Link for Dataverse networking: How to setup a secure connection?

Tags: azure, security, hyperlink, azure-synapse, dataverse

In the documentation for Synapse Link for Dataverse/Synapse Analytics it is stated that "you must enable public network access for Azure resources for both initial setup and delta sync."

As a newbie in networking, this raises some security concerns for me. A colleague pointed out to use private endpoints, but doesn't that only work with resources within the Vnet? Does the Synapse Link (within the Power Platform) count as such a resource? Also Synapse Link doesnt have a static IP that could be whitelisted.

The documentation only gets me more confused and I can't find any concrete setup, visual or video that addresses my question.

I would really appreciate someone who could explain how this works / is set up.

Thanks!

I read the documentation, but it isnt specific enough.

Comment: Saw sqlbits presentation recently where presenter said solving this was being tested but not yet production.  So I'm assuming we can't yet solve this for the storage account.  Synapse analytics provides a method in it's firewall rules called Allow Azure Synapse Link for Azure SQL Database to bypass firewall rules.  The prerequisite is this command.......create credential [https://.........dfs.core.windows.net/dataverse-......] with identity='Managed Identity'.  But for the storage account itself, I haven't yet found solution.

Comment: Thanks you, I found the presentation you mentioned. It seems that we have to wait a bit indeed.